# Problema ao usar variável contadora dentro requisição XMLHttp/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, contador

Quando rodo a seguinte função sempre obtenho 0 como resultado. 
Gostaria de saber o porquê disso e se estou fazendo algo errado.
A função cadastro_socios_xlsx recebe um objeto e cadastra cada instância do mesmo no banco de dados, preciso da variável teste (que deve ser incrementada em uma unidade a cada instância devidamente cadastrada no banco) para uma verificação futura, mas a variável 'teste' só tem seu valor correto quando coloco o console.log dentro do request.onreadystatechange. Já tentei usar AJAX, porém acontece o mesmo...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function cadastro_socios_xlsx(tabela){
        var teste = 0;
        for(linha of tabela){
            if(formata_cpf_cnpj(linha['CPF/CNPJ']) && valida_cpf_cnpj(linha['CPF/CNPJ'])){
                if(linha['CPF/CNPJ'] == 14){
                    var pessoa = "fisica";
                }else var pessoa = "juridica";
                if (typeof linha['EMAIL'] == 'undefined') {
                    var email = "";
                }else var email = linha['EMAIL'];
                if (typeof linha['COMPLEMENTO'] == 'undefined') {
                    var complemento = "";
                }else var complemento = linha['COMPLEMENTO'];
                var data_nasc = "";
                var telefone = linha['TELEFONE'].replace(" ", "");


                var dados = {
                    "socio_nome": linha['NOME/RAZÃO SOCIAL'],
                    "pessoa": pessoa,
                    "email": email,
                    "telefone": telefone,
                    "cpf_cnpj": linha['CPF/CNPJ'],
                    "rua": linha['ENDEREÇO'],
                    "numero": linha['NÚMERO'],
                    "complemento": complemento,
                    "bairro": linha['BAIRRO'],
                    "estado": linha['UF'],
                    "cidade": linha['CIDADE'],
                    "data_nasc": data_nasc,
                    "cep":linha['CEP']
                };
                var dados = JSON.stringify(dados);
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                request.open('post', './cadastro_socio.php');
                request.send(dados);
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                        var r = JSON.parse(this.response);
                        if(r){
                            teste++;
                            //console.log(teste); quando coloco o console.log aqui ele mostra os valores incrementando
                        }
                    }
                }
                 //console.log(teste); quando coloco o console.log aqui ele sempre mostra o valor inicial da variável teste (0)
            }

        }
        return teste; //sempre retorna 0
    }
```

Comment: Matheus, isso está acontecendo, pois uma requisição em javascript é assíncrona, então sua função está retornando antes mesmo da requisição ter sido finalizada, dê uma lida: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas e https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Obrigado, utilizei o AJAX de forma síncrona e funcionou. Porém recebo no console uma mensagem dizendo: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check [link](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/), realmente usar de forma síncrona acaba afetando um pouco o desempenho por poder fazer apenas uma requisição por vez, mas por agora vai servir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando inicializa `XMLHttpRequest` através do método [`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) com apenas dois parâmetros você está informando ao sistema que está inicializando uma requisição assíncrona.

Em uma solicitação assíncrona o fluxo de execução da função não fica bloqueado quando 
envia uma requisição para o servidor com [`send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send), o código do callback só será executado quando o servidor der uma resposta ou informar timeout.

Já em uma solicitação síncrona o fluxo de execução da função se interrompe e só é retomado após o servidor fornecer uma resposta, e o fluxo de execução passar pelo callback. A solicitação síncrona [não aceita timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHTTPRequest#timeout).

```js
//Função de testes de requisição assíncrona HTTP simplificada
//O objetivo não é medir suceso ou não de uma requisição portanto:
//NÃO SERVE DE MODELO PARA CHAMADAS XMLHttpRequest
function testeAsync() {
  let teste = 0;
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.timeout = 5000; //timeout 5s

  //Faz uma requisição assíncrona a uma API de testes 
  request.open('post', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  request.onreadystatechange = function(r) {
    if (this.readyState != 4 && this.status != 200) return;
    teste++;
    console.log(`Teste assíncrono dentro do callback : teste = ${teste}`);
  }
  //É uma requição assíncrona o que signific que o fluxo de execução NÃO será retido aqui 
  request.send({
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1
  });
  //Provavelmente esse código será executado primeiro que o equivalente dentro do callback, 
  //O que significa que teste++; ainda não foi executado provavelmente retornando teste = 0, mas não é uma certeza
  console.log(`Teste assíncrono fora do callback: teste = ${teste}`);
}

//Função de testes de requisição síncrona HTTP simplificada
//O objetivo não é medir suceso ou não de uma requisição portanto:
//NÃO SERVE DE MODELO PARA CHAMADAS XMLHttpRequest
function testeSync() {
  let teste = 0;
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  //Faz uma requisição síncrona a uma API de testes 
  request.open('post', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', false);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  request.onreadystatechange = function(r) {
    if (this.readyState != 4 && this.status != 200) return;
    teste++;
    console.log(`Teste síncrono dentro do callback : teste = ${teste}`);
  }
  //É uma requição síncrona o que signific que o fluxo de execução SERÁ retido aqui. 
  request.send({
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1
  });
  //Esse código NÃO será executado primeiro que o equivalente dentro do callback, 
  //O que significa que teste++; com certeza foi executado retornando teste = 1
  console.log(`Teste síncrono fora do callback : teste = ${teste}`);
}


testeAsync();

testeSync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi pode ser um problema de escopo de variável tenta retornar a variável "teste" dentro da função "onreadystatechange",em vez de fora dela.