# array.push() dentro de callback de mysql.query (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js

Olá,
estou com um problema em adicionar um erro personalizado em um array de erros, na validação de um form com nodejs.
Já tentei mudar a abordagem mas não cheguei a uma solução,

```
    //PARTE 1
    let errors = []
    db.query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = ?', [emailregister], (err, result) => {
         if (result.length > 0) {
           errors.push ({ err_email_msg: 'Email já cadastrado' })
         }
    })

    //PARTE 2
    if (errors.length == 0) {
       db.query('INSERT INTO Users (`name`, `email`, `password`, `celnumber`, `genre`, `birthdate`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
      [name, emailregister, registerpwd, celnumber, genreOption, datanascimento], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err)
          res.send(err)
        else
          res.send('Register OK!')
      })
  } else {
    res.render('register', {
      errors,
      primeironome,
      sobrenome,
      emailregister,
      registerpwd,
      confirmpwd,
      celnumber,
      genreOption,
      datanascimento,
      title: 'Registre-se'
    })
  }
```

acontece que, ele esta entrando no if da parte 2, com errors.length == 0 sendo TRUE, mesmo passando pelo errors.push da parte 1.

Com um console.log() logo apos o errors.push dentro do if da parte 1, é imprimido o array de erros da forma correta, mas se posicionar o console.log apos o db.query da parte 1, imprime-se um array vazio. 
Porque esse errors.push() na parte 1 não funciona corretamente?

Comment: A chamada `db.query` é assíncrona.

Comment: São códigos diferentes, com propósito diferentes e ambientes diferentes, mas você está tendo o mesmo problema que usuário teve: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450720/137387

Comment: sabia que db.query é assincrona mas não estava sabendo lidar com isso. Após algumas leituras consegui resolver. Obrigado pelos comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver com:

```
db.connect(async () => { 
const result = await db.promise().query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = ?', [emailregister]) 
if (result[0].length) { 
errors.push({ err_email_msg: 'Email já cadastrado' }) 
} ...
```

Assim, pude fazer a condicional do array de erros normalmente no mesmo bloco

```
if (errors.length == 0){ 
db.query('INSERT INTO Users ...
```

Não sei se é a forma mais elegante, mas resolvi meu problema. Obrigado pelos comentários.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que `db.query` é assíncrono e a [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback/27182#27182) é chamada depois de o resto do código (o `if`/`else`)  acontecer. Ou seja, a array `errors` ainda não tem os dados do mysql.

Duas soluções:

a) Usa `async`/`await` [como fizeste](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451163/129):

```
// PARTE 1
db.connect(async () => { 
    const result = await db.promise().query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = ?', [emailregister]) 
    if (result[0].length) { 
        errors.push({ err_email_msg: 'Email já cadastrado' }) 
    }
});

// PARTE 2
... etc
```

b) Coloca o resto da lógica dentro da callback:

```js
// PARTE 1
let errors = []
db.query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = ?', [emailregister], (err, result) => {
  if (result.length > 0) {
    errors.push({
      err_email_msg: 'Email já cadastrado'
    })
  }


  //PARTE 2
  if (errors.length == 0) {
    db.query('INSERT INTO Users (`name`, `email`, `password`, `celnumber`, `genre`, `birthdate`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [name, emailregister, registerpwd, celnumber, genreOption, datanascimento], (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err)
        res.send(err)
      else
        res.send('Register OK!')
    })
  } else {
    res.render('register', {
      errors,
      primeironome,
      sobrenome,
      emailregister,
      registerpwd,
      confirmpwd,
      celnumber,
      genreOption,
      datanascimento,
      title: 'Registre-se'
    })
  }
})
```